# Prove the following: If m<n, then m+p<n+p

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I have been asked to prove the following and have been having some difficulty:

Let m,n and p be integers. If *m*<*n* then *m+p*<*n+p*

This is my proof thus far. It feels a bit sloppy and I'm also worried that my last part (indicated by ***) is wrong. I have not yet proved subtraction so don't think I can use it. Can anybody maybe check what I have so far and advise me on potential directions to explore? Thanks!

1. By Prop 2.2 we know that all **N** must be greater than zero. We then can determine that *n-m*>0.
2. By the additive inverse identity, we can obtain *n-m+p-p*>0
3. By commutativity, we obtain *n+p-m-p*>0.
4. ***Then, I desperately want to be able todo *n+p>m+p*, but I'm pretty sure this is incorrect since I haven't yet 'proved' subtraction. How do I get out of this? And also, am I on the right track?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $1$ you probably have to prove that $n-m\in\Bbb{N}$.Other then that you should probably mention what you've learned so far(what you can use).

Comment: Hmm. So far we have learned about addition and multiplication in the integers, and the definition of the natural numbers. The proof I am working on comes from a section on ordering the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (since it's not obvious what properties you have proved already, and are allowed to use): for a minimalistic proof, consider induction in $p$ to prove it for $p \ge 0$. Then use $m+p \lt n+p$ $\iff$ $(-n)+(-p) \lt (-m)+(-p)$ to prove it for negative $p$ using the previous step.

For $p=0$ the inequality reduces to the premise $m \lt n$, thus holds.

Assuming it holds for $p \ge 0$ that means $m+p \lt n+p$. But in integer numbers:

- $a \lt b$ $\iff$ $a+1 \le b$ (since the next larger integer than $a$ is $a+1$), so $m+p+1 \le n+p\,$;
- $a+1 \le b$ $\iff$ $a+1 \lt b+1$ (since the next larger integer than $b$ is $b+1$), so $m+p+1 \lt n+p+1\,$, which completes the induction step.

The above proves the statement for $p \ge 0$. If $p \lt 0$ then use the already proven statement for $-p \gt 0$ with integers $-n \lt -m$ to obtain $(-n)+(-p) \lt (-m)+(-p)$ $\iff$ $m+p \lt n+p\,$.

(*The only properties of integer inequalities that were used are: $\;a \lt b \iff a+1 \le b\;$ and: $\;a \lt b \iff -b \lt -a\;$.*)